# How to sample posterior of two parameters using Metropolis Hastings?

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling, prior, posterior

Suppose I have n $(n=100)$ data. $X=(x_1,...,x_n)$, and $x_i \sim N(\mu,1/\phi)$.

Given priors $p(\mu,\phi) \propto 1/\phi$. the posterior of these two parameters is :

$$p(\mu,\phi|X) \propto \phi^{n/2-1} exp(-\frac{\phi}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\mu)^2)$$

How to sample $\mu$ and $\phi$ using M-H sampler? currently, I have two choices:

1. Sampling these two parameters in two separate loop at each time step.

   (In this situation, suppose I want sampling $\mu$, should i use $\phi(t-1)$ or a fixed number for $\phi$ in target distribution?)
2. Sampling these two parameters in completely two different time loop.

Which one is correct? Can anyone give some suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: It is not quite clear what the two approaches you mention are. Proposing (according to some bivariate proposal distribution) and accepting both parameters jointly would be the most vanilla M-H sampler. Sampling one given a fixed value for the other and then the other given a fixed value for the first is more typically called Gibbs sampling (although I believe it may technically also be a M-H sampler).

Comment: This is a very standard model that pops in every (modern) (Bayesian) textbook, including mines'. I thus presume this is in connection with an homework or course, in which case a `self-study` tag would seem necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Given a two-dimensional parameter $(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ and a target density $\pi(\theta_1,\theta_2)$, you can implement numerous Metropolis-Hastings moves among which

1. Generate a proposed value from a joint distribution with associated density $\varpi(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ and accept this proposed value with the Metropolis-Hastings acceptance probability;
2. Generate a proposed value one parameter at a time from a one-dimensional  proposal distribution $\varpi_i(\theta_i)$ and accept this proposal with the Metropolis-Hastings acceptance probability;

In particular, if the component-wise proposal is the full conditional, this corresponds to the regular Gibbs sampler, as illustrated below.

*[Excerpt from our book [Introducing Monte Carlo Methods with R](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441915753), Example 7.3, pp.202-203, with a few typos corrected]*

Consider the posterior distribution on $(\theta,\sigma^2)$ associated with the joint model
\begin{eqnarray} 
X_i &\sim& {\cal N}(\theta,\sigma^2), \quad i=1, \ldots, n, \\
\theta &\sim& {\cal N}(\theta_0,\tau^2\sigma^2)\,,\quad
\sigma^2 \sim {\cal IG}(a,b),\nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
where ${\cal IG}(a,b)$ is the inverted Gamma distribution
(that is, the distribution of the inverse of a Gamma variable),
with density $b^a (1/x)^{a+1}e^{-b/x}/\Gamma(a)$ and with $\theta_0, \tau^2, a, b$ specified.
Writing $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, \ldots,x_n)$, the posterior distribution on $(\theta,\sigma^2)$ is given by
\begin{eqnarray}\label{eq:firstjoint}
f(\theta,\sigma^2|\mathbf{x}) &\propto& \left[\frac{1}{(\sigma^2)^{n/2}}e^{-\sum_i(x_i-\theta)^2\big/2\sigma^2}\right] \\
&&\times \left[\frac{1}{\tau\sigma }e^{-(\theta-\theta_0)^2/2\tau^2\sigma^2}\right] \times \left[\frac{1}{(\sigma^2)^{a+1}}e^{-1/b \sigma^2}\right],\nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
from which we can get the full conditionals of $\theta$ and $\sigma^2$. (Note that this is not a regular conjugate setting in
that integrating $\theta$ or $\sigma^2$ in this density does not produce a standard density.)
We have
\begin{eqnarray}\label{eq:firstposterior}
\pi(\theta | \mathbf{x},\sigma^2) &\propto&e^{-\sum_i(x_i-\theta)^2/2\sigma^2}e^{-(\theta-\theta_0)^2/2\tau^2 \sigma^2}\,,  \\
&&\\
\pi(\sigma^2 | \mathbf{x},\theta) &\propto&  \left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\right)^{(n+2a+3)/2}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \left(\sum_i(x_i-\theta)^2+(\theta-\theta_0)^2/\tau^2 +2/b\right)\right\}\,.  
\end{eqnarray}
These densities correspond to
$$
\theta | \mathbf{x},\sigma^2\sim
{\cal N}\left(\frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+n \tau^2}\;\theta_0 + \frac{n\tau^2}{\sigma^2+n \tau^2} 
\;\bar x, \; \frac{\sigma^2 \tau^2}{\sigma^2+n \tau^2}\right) 
$$
and
$$
\sigma^2 | \mathbf{x},\theta \sim {\cal IG}\left(\frac{n}{2}+a, \frac{1}{2}\sum_i( x_i - \theta)^2+b \right),
$$
where $\bar x$ is the empirical average of the observations,
as the full conditional distributions to be used in a Gibbs sampler.

A study on metabolism in 15-year-old females yielded the following data, denoted by $\mathbf{x}$,

```
> x=c(91,504,557,609,693,727,764,803,857,929,970,1043,
+     1089,1195,1384,1713)
> x=log(x)
```

corresponding to their energy intake, measured in megajoules,
over a 24 hour period. Using the normal model above, with $\theta$ corresponding to the
true mean energy intake, the Gibbs sampler can be implemented as

```
> xbar=mean(x)
> sh1=(n/2)+a
> sigma2=theta=rep(0,Nsim)                  #init arrays
> sigma2[1]=1/rgamma(1,shape=a,rate=b)      #init chains
> B=sigma2[1]/(sigma2[1]+n*tau2)
> theta[1]=rnorm(1,m=B*theta0+(1-B)*xbar,sd=sqrt(tau2*B)
> for (i in 2:Nsim){
+   B=sigma2[i-1]/(sigma2[i-1]+n*tau2)
+   theta[i]=rnorm(1,m=B*theta0+(1-B)*xbar,sd=sqrt(tau2*B))
+   ra1=(1/2)*(sum((x-theta[i])^2))+b
+   sigma2[i]=1/rgamma(1,shape=sh1,rate=ra1)
+   }
```

where `theta0`, `tau2`, `a`, and `b` are specified values.
The posterior means of $\theta$ and $\sigma^2$ are 872.402 and 136,229.2, giving as an estimate of $\sigma$ 369.092.
Histograms of the posterior distributions of $\theta$ and $\sigma$ are given in the following Figure.

[image: 2]

Comment: I thought you were going to give an example where you accept / reject the Gibbs Sampler draws. Instead, you gave code for regular Gibbs Sampler. Do you have one which uses Metropolis Hastings for either of the either of the two options you listed?

Comment: @bhomass: there are plenty of such examples on our book indeed.